# button click event stopped after new integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, buttonclick

I have been implementing the DPS (http://sec.paymentexpress.com/technical_resources/ecommerce_hosted/pxpay.html) sample code for ASP.Net (C#) to create a payment gateway for my company. I had it working fine, sending requests to Payment Express, getting responses, etc., just like it should.

Then, I tried to integrate it with my system. I added some references from my project, gave it a base class to inherit and moved the "look up / add to the database" function to another class.

After all that, I tested it again and the button click event is not firing. I thought it might be something to do with the new inheritance, so I changed my page to inherit "Page" (like it did before), but that hasn't helped.

The "look up / add to the database" function comes in later, so I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Is anyone aware of what might have possibly gone wrong?

To clarify, I say the event is not firing because I threw an exception as the first line in the event and the exception is not throwing. The button DOES seem to do a postback, though.

Here is some code:

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs"  
Inherits="PaymentGatewayDPS._Default" enableViewState="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>PxPay .Net 3.5 test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Amount
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmountInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Currency
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrencyInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Reference
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMerchantReference" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Transaction type
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTxnType" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Purchase</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Auth">Authorisation</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit"
OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Literal id="LitTest" runat="server"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Beginning of My C# Code:

```
namespace PaymentGatewayDPS
{
public partial class _Default : TCInsuredQuoteBase
{
```

My Button Event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("button clicked");
        string PxPayUserId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PxPayUserId"];
        string PxPayKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PxPayKey"];

        PxPay WS = new PxPay(PxPayUserId, PxPayKey);

        RequestInput input = new RequestInput();

        input.AmountInput = txtAmountInput.Text;
        input.CurrencyInput = txtCurrencyInput.Text;
        input.MerchantReference = txtMerchantReference.Text;
        input.TxnType = ddlTxnType.Text;
        input.UrlFail = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
        input.UrlSuccess = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

        // TODO: GUID representing unique identifier for the transaction within the shopping cart (normally would be an order ID or similar)
        Guid orderId = Guid.NewGuid();
        input.TxnId = orderId.ToString();
        throw new Exception("about to Generate Request");

        RequestOutput output = WS.GenerateRequest(input);

        if (output.valid == "1")
        {
            // Redirect user to payment page
            Response.Redirect(output.Url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: cant you try debugging your code to see if its coming tll throw statement?

Comment: See, there's a problem there. I am using MonoDevelop and the way our code is organised, debug doesn't work. It's a real pain. That's why I was using exceptions.

Comment: Did you set AutoEventWireup to true in your aspx markup?

Comment: Yes, AutoEventWireup is true.

Comment: can you show us some code from your aspx as well as .cs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! It was something specific to DPS. I had changed the transaction ID to something longer than 16 characters and the request was failing. I just couldn't see it happening, which is why it was taking me so long to find. Thank you for your suggestions.